# What does "getting it" mean in this phrase?

Tags: phrases

As English is not my mother tongue, I need someone to explain the phrases "getting it" and "adequate mantra" in the following paragraph:

> Their shows are sold out within 10 seconds after they go on sale, completely breaking the old notion that it‘s impossible to wield success solely off rap in Korea.In the purest sense, Dok2 and The Quiett are Korea's first real, rap superstars. Young, rich, and **getting it**, is an **adequate mantra** for these two indie rap bosses.

Answer (score 3):

[Mantra](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mantra):

> - a commonly repeated word or phrase, especially in advocacy or for motivation.

The repetition of these three words, which define their specific reality,  *Young, Rich, and Getting It* is like a mantra, a sort of "spiritual prayer". Close to the style of their songs.

Getting it refers to gettting  what they want, what they like (also with a sexual innuendo)

Answer (score 2):

The noun [***mantra***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mantra) is originally a word or sound repeated to aid concentration in meditation in Hinduism or Buddhism. It also means:

> A statement or ***slogan*** repeated frequently.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

***Getting it*** could have multiple meanings, but it seems to mean ***to be successful*** by understanding the trend of the pop or music culture in your country to the extent that their tickets could be sold out within 10 seconds.